# Hide / Show Sidebar over Jquery is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I apologize in advance for my English**

Hello people ...

I have these scripts to hide / display the Sidebar but its functionality is not correct and I have had enough discussion than I wrote here ... so

**HTML LINK**

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="sidebar-toggle-box">
  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="container" class="">
 <div id="sidebar">
  <ul class="sidebar-menu">
   <li><a href="">bla bla bla</a>
  </ul>
</div>
 </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**& jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // for mobile check
    function mobilecheck() {
        var check = false;
        (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
        return check;
    };

    $(function() {
        function responsiveView() {
            if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
                $('#container').addClass('sidebar-close');
                $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
            }
            if ($(window).width() > 768) {
                $('#container').removeClass('sidebar-close');
                $('#sidebar > ul').show();
            }
        }

        $(window).on('load', responsiveView);
        $(document).on('click', function(){
           if(mobilecheck()){
               $(window).on('resize', responsiveView);
           }
        });
    });

    $('.sidebar-toggle-box').click(function () {

        if ($('#sidebar > ul').is(":visible") === true) {
            $('#main-content').css({
                'margin-left': '0px'
            });
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'margin-left': '-210px'
            });
            $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
            $("#container").addClass("sidebar-closed");
        } else {
            $('#main-content').css({
                'margin-left': '210px'
            });
            $('#sidebar > ul').show();
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'margin-left': '0'
            });
            $("#container").removeClass("sidebar-closed");
        }
        var owl = $("#owl-demo").data("owlCarousel");
        owl.reinit();
    });
});
```

**Well now to the problem:**

***Issue 1***

If you reduce the size of the #container page, it extends correctly to the full width and the #sidebar is hidden as well as the proper functionality.
Well, when I click on # sidebar-toggle-box so #sidebar does not expand until F5 page refreshes then hiding / viewing works properly ...

***Problem 2***

If I see and then hide #sidebar in a smaller version and expand or enlarge the page, the #sidebar remains hidden and will not appear until the page is restored, but I need to see it without refreshing the page ....

So please do not you have any functional code to solve these problems or the best links to help?

**All for reply / help thanks.**

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Did you have this in the code?

Comment: **@DeepakDholiyan**  yes I have these meta tags in the header `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`